# Find the mistake of the inductive proof for $r^n=1$

Tags: induction, fake-proofs

> Find the mistake in the following proof that purports to show that
>   every nonnegative integer power of every nonzero real number is 1.

Let $r$ be any nonzero real number and let the property $P(n)$ be the equation
"$r^n=1$".

**Basis**

The property is true for $n=0$ by definition of the zeroth power.

**Hypothesis**

Let $k>0$ be an integer and suppose that $r^i=1$ for all integers $i$ with $0\leq i <k.$

Now

$r^k = r^{(k-1)+(k-1)-(k-2)}$

$ = \frac{r^{(k-1)} \cdot r^{(k-1)}}{r^{(k-2)}}$ by laws of exponent

$= \frac{1* 1}{1}=1$ by hypothesis

Thus, $r^k=1 $ as was to be shown.

Since we have proved the basis step and inductive step, we conclude that 
$r^n =1$ for all integers $n\geq1$.

---

I know it's obviously wrong, but the logic looks so convincing. Nonetheless, my guess is that it is misusing the laws of exponents; however, I don't know how to explain the deception of the proof in thorough detail.So, how is it wrong, and where?

Comment: What happens when $k=1$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I know that you could uses when n=2 as a counter example, but the goal of this problem is to find where the mistake is.

Comment: To rephrase @MihirSinghal's answer: $k=0$ does not imply $k=1$ in your inductive argument and the reason is exactly as Alex noted.

Comment: If the result were true when $k=1$, then the induction would work.  If you try to prove the case where $k=1$ using the induction, then you'll find that you don't have the right assumptions to use the inductive step.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need two base cases ($n=0$ and $n=1$), since you're using $r^{k-2}=1$. The $n=1$ case is clearly false, so the proof is wrong.

Comment: So in strong induction we have to check for two base cases? Because in my text book it says let a and b be fixed integers with $"a\leq b"$ Is it possible to have a=b, as in this "proof" a=b=1. Basis: P(a), P(a+1),...,P(b) are true.

Comment: When $n=1$, you cannot use this proof because $n-2=-1$ is not in the range of consideration. You do not always need two base cases for strong induction, but this subtlety in the proof you give here requires it.

Comment: This is just repeating Alex's comment in different words, but I hope it might help anyway. Your induction hypothesis was, as you said, $r^i=1$ for integers $i$ in the range $0\leq i<k$. You then applied this for two values of $i$, namely $k-1$ and $k-2$. So you need $0\leq k-1<k$ and $0\leq k-2<k$. For both of those to be true, you need $2\leq k$. So your induction step won't work when $k=1$. Specifically, when $k=1$, then the value $k-2$ of $i$ that you want to use in the induction hypothesis is not in the available range $0\leq i<k$ because it's $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

I think general rule can be formulated as follows:

- Assume that $b\in\mathbb{N}$ is the basis
- Express induction hypothesis $P(n)$ in terms of $P(n-1), P(n-2), ..., P(n-k)$

Then before proving the hypothesis $P(n)$ you must check $P(b), P(b+1), ..., P(b+k-1)$ "by hand". And in this case you actually have $k$ bases. This is because you can never obtain these properties as the result of hypothesis. For example, if you take  $n=b+k-1$ you get $P(b+k-1)=F\big(P(b+k-2), ..., \color{red}{P(b-1)}\big)$ which is illegal.

In your example the hypothesis can be expressed (symbolically) as:
$$P(n) = \frac{P(n-1)  P(n-1)}{P(n-2)},$$ with $P(0)$ as the basis. So you have to prove $P(0)$ and $P(1)$ separately.